# I can't create an iTunes Connect user with an email containing a plus sign

Tags: email, app-store-connect

I used to be able to add or be added as a user to an iTunes Connect team with an email containing a plus sign. This was convenient because I was able to be part of multiple iTunes Connect teams with the same Gmail email address (emails sent to foo+bar@gmail.com always go to foo@gmail.com). Now I am getting the error `The email address you entered is invalid. Please try again.`

Is using emails with a plus sign no longer possible? Is there a workaround?

Comment: I'm running into the same issue.  As my company has access to around 100 different itunesconnect accounts it was a huge pain before we started using the + trick to either setup a unique email address for each one or to force the clients to create us a unique email addresses. I guess we can hope it's a bug and not a new policy or that they start allowing a single email address to be invited to multiple itunes connect accounts (like google play and amazon do).

Comment: Sadly, 3 years later and you still can't add a plus. Though I have some legacy that have the plus still in them.

Comment: and in 2021 still a problem...

Comment: and in 2023 still a problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can invite the same email address to multiple accounts now.  I just invited the same email (without +) to two different accounts and now I can see both from the single account (similar to how google play handles it).  At the top right it will allow you to switch between companies you have access to.